# Looking for a specific mining pool

Tags: mining-pools, altcoin

I'm developing a mining application that switches mining between different altcoins. I'm looking for a mining pool with an API that allows withdraws, so that I can automate the withdraw process for each user. Are there any pools with this feature available? Thanks in advance!